# How to make up a unique name for a $_SESSION in PHP?

Tags: php, session, networking, ip

As part of the login system I'm making, I keep track of failed login attempts inside a unique session named after each client:

```
if($login_failed) {

            // update failed login attempts
            $session_name = 'failed_attempts'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            if(!isset($_SESSION[$session_name])) {
                $_SESSION[$session_name] = 1;               
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION[$session_name] += 1;  
            }

}
```

As you can see, to determine a unique name for each session I append the user's IP address to the end of the string "failed_login_attempts".

If the user reaches 5 failed attempts I require a captcha to be filled out on each subsequent attempt.

I'm just worried that there might be some networks where many users are assigned the same IP address, in which case if 1 users fails to login they would all start seeing captchas even though only that 1 user needs to be shown the captcha.

Is this reasonable or is there never a situation where 2 users can have the same IP, for example they may have the same first 3 octets but the last number will be different in which case I don't have to worry.

If there is a chance of multiple users sharing the same IP then what is a good way to determine a unique identifier for my session name that will link a non-logged in user to the session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The session **is already unique**, as it is tied to a cookie for that particular user, on that particular browser. You don't need to worry about it spilling across to other users.

The [session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is what ties all this together.

What is actually happening behind the scenes is that PHP stores a cookie on the browser with a unique id (the session id) which is associated with a data structure stored on the server. None of the actual session data ever leaves the server, apart from that id. It's actually a file, you can see it if you poke around in your php folders.

Comment: right but what do I put in the spot of the question marks to actually see if atleast 5 failed attempts have been made --------> if(isset($_SESSION[???]) && $_SESSION[???] == '5')

Comment: In other words how do I associate a failed session with a user, since the user isn't logged in yet.

Comment: store the number of attempts in a variable, and if it's bigger than 5, do your logic. it's really that simple. however, as it is cookie based, you may want to store some kind of alert in the db for that user.

Comment: as michael points out below, if the user clears their cookies, they can go for another try, which is why I mention storing an alert somewhere.

Comment: Storing the failed attempts in a database would cause the same issue though. Because even then I need to associate the failed attempts with a particular user. That's why I was trying to use the IP in the session name. Still need a way to uniquely associate failed attempts with a particular user.

Comment: in that case, you need to up the sophistication, and look at storing data associated with that attempt to login. User-agent string, IP, user-name, number of attempts. You could make a hash of these values to make storage easier too.

Comment: it seems like you're on the right tracks already though - just think it through and you'll get there :)

Answer (score 1):

In most school, home, and office networks your users *will* be sharing IP addresses since they will be accessing the broader Internet from inside a NAT or through an outbound firewall.  Use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate a unique value to associate with each failure.  That is not entirely necessary though, because [`session_id()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) holds a unique value for each user session already.

All you really need to do to track failures in a session is to increment a variable inside that session.

```
if (failed_login) {
  $_SESSION['failed_logins']++;
}

$threshold = 5;
if ($_SESSION['failed_logins'] >= $threshold) {
   // Do whatever is needed when too many failures occur
}
```

Note however, that this can't prevent a user from simply restarting the browser to get a new session.  You can add more hoops to jump through, like also logging the user agent, but that can also cause potential conflicts for other users on the same network and can still be spoofed or changed by clever end users to get around your restriction.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to flag/increment a column in your user table and when it hits 5, trigger the captcha code.  Once successfully logged in, reset the value to 0.

Comment: I disagree. This seems like valuable advice, and the question doesn't really allow for much code in the answers. I'd like some details on how to trigger a captcha code from a database trigger though...